# How to add two swiftmodule?

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to add static lib that use internally other libs, so the structure looks like this

[image]

The problem is that under the lib dir I have two directories `.swiftmodule`

```
Lib.swiftmodule

IOSStatic.swiftmodule
```

they both are trying to copy their content to the build dir and as a result, I get such an error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-evoarbsjaphalweicycrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestProject.app/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo':
1) Target 'TestProject' (project 'TestProject') has copy command from '/Users//Buffer/iOS_projects/TestProject/TestProject/lib/Lib.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo' to '/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-evoarbsjaphalweicycrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestProject.app/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo'
2) Target 'TestProject' (project 'TestProject') has copy command from '/Users//Buffer/iOS_projects/TestProject/TestProject/lib/IOSStatic.swiftmodule/Project/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo' to '/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-evoarbsjaphalweicycrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestProject.app/arm64-apple-ios.swiftsourceinfo'
```

But, as my lib use internally two static libs I need two `.swiftmodule` (one of each internal libs)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When this is your own lib, why not just using a Swift Package which you build from the sources?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have added `.swiftsourceinfo` (and others) files to your target from your swift modules, but you don't need ones - you need to add library `.a` files to link only.